# Can't change inputs value on submit

Tags: angular, typescript

in input when a person writes age I am sending this value as a date (API is built like that) for example like this:

> "2021-04-22T21:13:36.211Z"

I am trying to change this value when submitting with the setValue method, but i get error: **setValue is not a function**

here is my code:

```
 onSubmit() {
    const birthDateValue = (this.formGroup.get('formArray') as FormArray).at(0).get('birthDate').value
    const date = new Date();
    const year = date.getFullYear() - birthDateValue;
    date.setFullYear(year);
    birthDateValue.setValue(date.toISOString());

    console.log(date.toISOString());
    console.log(this.formGroup.value);
  }
```

my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-starter-6xojcb?file=app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you have to take the control of birthDate:

```
 onSubmit() {
   const birthDateValue = (this.formGroup.get("formArray") as FormArray)
     .at(0)
     .get("birthDate").value;
   const birthDateValueControl = (this.formGroup.get("formArray") as FormArray)
     .at(0)
     .get("birthDate");
   const date = new Date();
   const year = date.getFullYear() - birthDateValue;
   date.setFullYear(year);
   birthDateValueControl.setValue(date.toISOString());

   console.log(date.toISOString());
   console.log(this.formGroup.value)
 }
```

The mistake is that you are trying to call setValue on a value not on a controlForm.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can inputs placeholder not change?

Comment: What do you mean?
If the answer is correct please don't forget to mark it as solution.

Comment: sure it is correct, thx! check stackblitz i updated it, i mean that inputs placeholder changes as date too, can it stay as a age?